# What TypeScript type should I use to reference the match object in my props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

In my React containers/component, which type could I use to reference the `match` part included by React Router DOM?

```
interface Props {
  match: any // <= What could I use here instead of any?
}

export class ProductContainer extends React.Component<Props> {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You don't need to add it explicitly. You can use `RouteComponentProps<P>` from `@types/react-router` as a base interface of your props instead. `P` is type of your match params.

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

// example route
<Route path="/products/:name" component={ProductContainer} />

interface MatchParams {
    name: string;
}

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<MatchParams> {
}
```

```
// from typings
import * as H from "history";

export interface RouteComponentProps<P> {
  match: match<P>;
  location: H.Location;
  history: H.History;
  staticContext?: any;
}

export interface match<P> {
  params: P;
  isExact: boolean;
  path: string;
  url: string;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that Typescript then expects every use of that component to be actually passed in location history props etc. RouteComponentProps should have those props as optional. Have to wrap with Partial.

Comment: @Glstunna thanks for making me aware, how would that look like with partial? As well OP: please include your imports.

Comment: TypeScript keeps asking me to pass the whole props set down to the component (`<MyComp history={...} location={...} .../>, I have the same code as seen above.

Comment: @LeonardoViada Try passing the component using `<Route component={MyComp} />`

Answer (score 42):

To add onto @Nazar554's answer above, the `RouteComponentProps` type should be imported from `react-router-dom`, and implemented as follows.

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface MatchParams {
    name: string;
}

interface MatchProps extends RouteComponentProps<MatchParams> {
}
```

Further, to allow for re-usable components, the `render()` function allows you to pass only what the component needs, rather than the entire `RouteComponentProps`.

```
<Route path="/products/:name" render={( {match}: MatchProps) => (
    <ProductContainer name={match.params.name} /> )} />

// Now Product container takes a `string`, rather than a `MatchProps`
// This allows us to use ProductContainer elsewhere, in a non-router setting!
const ProductContainer = ( {name}: string ) => {
     return (<h1>Product Container Named: {name}</h1>)
}
```

Comment: Awesome! nice supplement

Answer (score 10):

Simple solution

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

const Container = ({ match }: RouteComponentProps<{ showId?: string}>) => {
 const { showId } = match.params?.showId;//in case you need to take params
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that even after creating an interface for the `match<Params>` the type warning was still there. Here is the code which worked for me:

```js
interface MatchParams {
    firstParam: string;
    optionalParam?: string;
}

export const CreditPortfolioDetail: FC<RouteComponentProps<MatchParams>> = (props) => {
    const { firstParam, optionalParam} = props.match.params; 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What is FC ? FC<RouteComponentProps<MatchParams>>

Comment: It's React.FC, which is a type alias for React.FunctionComponent. Your function is actually a FunctionComponent, and by explicitly stating that, you also get the children property automatically added to your props (similar to how RouteComponentProps automatically adds location, match, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete example I tested.

**DemoComponent.tsx**

```
// Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2021/9/25 20:15

import React from "react";
import {RouteComponentProps} from "react-router"

export default class DemoComponent extends React.Component<{
    prop1: string,
    prop2: string,
    prop3: string
} & RouteComponentProps<{
    param1: string,
    param2: string,
    param3: string
}>, {
    state1: string,
    state2: string,
    state3: string
}> {

    static defaultProps = {
        prop1: "PROP1",
        prop2: "PROP2",
        prop3: "PROP3"
    }

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            state1: "STATE1",
            state2: "STATE2",
            state3: "STATE3"
        }
    }


    render() {
        return <ul>
            <li>prop1 = {this.props.prop1}</li>
            <li>prop2 = {this.props.prop2}</li>
            <li>prop3 = {this.props.prop3}</li>
            <li>state1 = {this.state.state1}</li>
            <li>state2 = {this.state.state2}</li>
            <li>state3 = {this.state.state3}</li>
            <li>param1 = {this.props.match.params.param1}</li>
            <li>param2 = {this.props.match.params.param2}</li>
            <li>param3 = {this.props.match.params.param3}</li>
        </ul>
    }
}
```

**The route**

```
<Route exact path="/demo/:param1/:param2/:param3" component={DemoComponent}/>
```

**The call**

```
/demo/foo/bar/baz
```

**The result**

```
prop1 = PROP1
prop2 = PROP2
prop3 = PROP3
state1 = STATE1
state2 = STATE2
state3 = STATE3
param1 = foo
param2 = bar
param3 = baz
```