# React Link params of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Params is undefined in `ItemPage`. I can't seem to see the issue here. Any takers?

Basically trying to create a dynamic path with `Link`
.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/catalog"  component={Catalog} />
        <Route path="/about"  component={About} />
        <Route path="/item/:nm" component={ItemPage}/>
        <Route render={() => <h1>404: page not found</h1>} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )}
```

```
function Catalog() {
  return (
    <div className="Catalog">
        {Routes.map((route, index) => {
            return <p key={index}><Link to={`/item/${route.name}`}> {route.name} </Link></p>
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const ItemPage = ({match:{params:{nm}}}) => {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Item {nm} Page</h1>
    <ItemPage name={nm}/>
  </div>
  )
  };
```

Comment: it seems right ... have you try with hook "const { nm } = useParams();"

Answer (score 0):

if you use `react-router-dom` package, then this method might help you then:-

- `ItemPage` (use `useParam` hook):-

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const ItemPage = () => {
  const { nm } = useParams()

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Item {nm} Page</h1>
      <ItemPage name={nm}/>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the way you have your props set up on `ItemPage` is exactly correct - in my experience using `react-router` I've always just used `match` as its own parameter without defining its properties like so:

```
const ItemPage = ({match}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Item {nm} Page</h1>
      <ItemPage name={match.params.nm}/>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Another option could be to use the routecomponent props and do some destructuring to pull out `match`:

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

const ItemPage : FC<RouteComponentProps> = (props) => {
  const {match} = props
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Item {nm} Page</h1>
      <ItemPage name={match.params.nm}/>
    </div>
  )
};
```

(see here: [What TypeScript type should I use to reference the match object in my props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138111/what-typescript-type-should-i-use-to-reference-the-match-object-in-my-props))

Answer (score 0):

Basically the nested `<ItemPage name={nm}/>` was the issue. It should be replaced with a different component or HTML.

https://github.com/Tyler90901/webtech/pull/1/commits/16b337bc2e45ef0f06bc41f1fc060b87a8bc9d36